# Save to decimal and list not working SQL Server 2008 and C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, sql-server-2008, entity-framework

I am saving some data coming from a KML file. To have any value, I created my database in this way.

```
create table PONTO
( 
    PontoID int not null identity, 
    ClienteID int null, 
    Descricao varchar(255) not null, 
    Latitude numeric(18,15) not null, 
    Longitude numeric(18,15) not null, 
    Altura decimal(12,2) null 
)

alter table PONTO add constraint PK_Ponto primary key (PontoID)

create table LINK
( 
    LinkID int not null identity, 
    PontoOrigemID int null, 
    PontoDestinoID int null, 
    LatitudeOrigem numeric(18,15) not null, 
    LongitudeOrigem numeric(18,15) not null, 
    LatitudeDestino numeric(18,15) not null, 
    LongitudeDestino numeric(18,15) not null, 
    Descricao varchar(255) not null, 
    Detalhes text null, 
    Altura decimal(12, 2) null, 
    Distancia decimal(12, 3) null, 
    AzimuteOrigemDestino decimal(3, 2) null, 
    AzimuteDestinoOrigem decimal(3, 2) null, 
    Velocidade varchar(50) null 
) 

alter table LINK add constraint PK_Link primary key (LinkID)
```

I tried to create a float, but when trying to join did not work.

My class to save data is this:

```
public class Ponto
{
    public int PontoID { get; set; }
    public int? ClienteID { get; set; }
    public string Descricao { get; set; }
    public Double Latitude { get; set; }
    public Double Longitude { get; set; }
    public Double? Altura { get; set; }
}

public class Link
{
    [Key]
    public int LinkID { get; set; }

    public int? PontoOrigemID { get; set; }
    public int? PontoDestinoID { get; set; }        
    public Double LatitudeOrigem { get; set; }
    public Double LongitudeOrigem { get; set; }
    public Double LatitudeDestino { get; set; }
    public Double LongitudeDestino { get; set; }

    public string Descricao { get; set; }
    public string Detalhes { get; set; }        

    public Double? Altura { get; set; }
    public Double? Distancia { get; set; }
    public Double? AzimuteOrigemDestino { get; set; }
    public Double? AzimuteDestinoOrigem { get; set; }
    public string Velocidade { get; set; }        
}
```

Save file KML:

```
public ActionResult CarregarArquivo()
{
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.Load(Server.MapPath(@"~\AppData\doc.xml"));

    var dados = new List<Ponto>();
    Ponto ponto;
    Link link;

    /*  Existe duas pastas folder dentro do arquivo, a primeira com os pontos,
        segunda com os links */
    foreach (XmlNode nodePrincipal in doc.SelectNodes("/kml/Document/Folder"))
    {
        /* Pontos definidos */
        foreach (XmlNode nodePontos in nodePrincipal.SelectNodes("Placemark"))
        {
            ponto = new Ponto();
            ponto.Descricao = nodePontos.SelectSingleNode("name").InnerText; /* Nome do ponto */                    
            var coord = nodePontos.SelectSingleNode("Point/coordinates").InnerText.Split(',');
            ponto.Longitude = Convert.ToDouble(coord[0].Replace('.', ','));
            ponto.Latitude = Convert.ToDouble(coord[1].Replace('.', ','));

            using (var db = new TCC.Models.ERPContext())
            {
                db.Ponto.Add(ponto);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
        /* Verifica se tem outra pasta folder, que indica que é uma pasta de links */
        foreach (XmlNode nodeEnlace in nodePrincipal.SelectNodes("Folder"))
        {
            link = new Link();
            link.Descricao = nodeEnlace.SelectSingleNode("name").InnerText;

            foreach (XmlNode nodeEnlacePonto in nodeEnlace.SelectNodes("Placemark"))
            {
                if (nodeEnlacePonto.Attributes["id"] != null)
                {

                    if (link.LatitudeOrigem == 0.0 && link.LongitudeOrigem == 0.0)
                    {
                        link.LatitudeOrigem = Convert.ToDouble(nodeEnlacePonto.SelectSingleNode("LookAt/latitude").InnerText.Replace('.', ','));
                        link.LongitudeOrigem = Convert.ToDouble(nodeEnlacePonto.SelectSingleNode("LookAt/longitude").InnerText.Replace('.', ','));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        link.LatitudeDestino = Convert.ToDouble(nodeEnlacePonto.SelectSingleNode("LookAt/latitude").InnerText.Replace('.', ','));
                        link.LongitudeDestino = Convert.ToDouble(nodeEnlacePonto.SelectSingleNode("LookAt/longitude").InnerText.Replace('.', ','));
                    }
                }
            }

            using (var db = new TCC.Models.ERPContext())
            {
                db.Link.Add(link);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
    }
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

The problem is when I try to grab the data and the system returns the error:

Unable to set property 'Latitude' in 'Point' with a value 'Decimal'. This property must be set to a non-null value of type 'Double'.

To list:

```
public JsonResult CarregaDados()
{
    using (var db = new ERPContext())
    {
        var dados = db.Ponto.ToList();
        return Json(dados.ToArray(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

What should I do to improve the process and make it work?

I using VS2008, SQL Server 2008, C# and Entity Framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's pretty starightforward - you've defined a bunch of numeric and decimal fields in the DB schema while the corresponding C# class has double for those fields - just try changing to decimal.

Comment: Hello, if seto as decimal values ​​are only 2 places after the comma and the rest zero. Takes other values​​, they can not break into two homes @vivek